# Getting errors when try to run the trigger using Liquidbase

Tags: java, mysql, triggers, liquibase

Error is below com.fme.servlets.listener.DatabaseVersionControlListener->runLiquibaseUpdate(String) : liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
1 changes have validation failures
Change Set ID: NFS-2072_3 Change Set Author: sgoswami
Change Type 'pro:createTrigger' is not allowed for MySQL.

And also I believe there would be a syntax error as well can anyone please correct me.

Comment: Look at [Liquidbase - Create trigger](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/pro/create-trigger.html) - you use attributes which are not listed in the documentation.

Comment: I am using this Liquid base xml   " <changeSet id="NFS-2072_9" author="sgoswami" runOnChange="true">
    <sqlFile path="phone_update_before.sql" 
             endDelimiter="/"
             relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
             <rollback>
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS  phone_update_before;
    </rollback>
</changeSet>"

Comment: Add facts to the question text, do not post them as comments.

Comment: every time I am getting exception " check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TRIGGER test.phone_update_before

Comment: Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - The prefix "pro" for element "pro:createTrigger" is not bound.
 - End tag of element <pro:createTrigger>

Comment: Change Type 'pro:createTrigger' is not allowed for MySQL.

Comment: @Akina could you please have a look now I just modify the xml as you suggested

Comment: Sorry, I do not use LiquidBase, I simply point that your initial code does not match official documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Liuidbase version 2.0.2 and Below is the liquid base XML.

```
 <changeSet id="XXX" author="sgoswami" dbms="mysql">

 <sql>  drop trigger if exists phone_update_before; </sql>   
 <sqlFile splitStatements="false" stripComments="false" path="phone_update_before.sql"    relativeToChangelogFile="true"/>
 
 </changeSet>
```